# the `-t` operator for the `test` command does not correctly identify non-tty file descriptors

Tags: fish

In bash/ksh/dash:

```
$ input_redirected() { [[ -t 0 ]] && echo input is not redirected || echo input is redirected; }
$ input_redirected foo
input is not redirected
$ input_redirected < /dev/null
input is redirected
$ cat /etc/passwd | input_redirected
input is redirected
```

in fish

```
$ function input_redirected; test -t 0; and echo not redirected; or echo redirected; end
$ input_redirected foo
not redirected
$ input_redirected < /dev/null
not redirected
$ cat /etc/passwd | input_redirected
not redirected
```

However, using `isatty 0` instead of `test -t 0` does provide the expected output.

What is `test -t FD` test doing in fish that it does not behave the same as POSIX-type shells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1228

The workaround is to use `command test`, which is also what `isatty` does - see `type isatty`.